# sql query about latest date

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery, max, greatest-n-per-group

I have these two tables.

```
UserProfiles(userid, attr , value)
InformationValues(attr , dateOfValue, price)
```

Table content:

Userprofiles for userid ='ann'

[image]

Informationvalues

[image]

Now I have to select for each attr the latest date and calculate the sum for the price for each attr the userid 'ann' has.

[image]

The sum price for the userid 'ann' of each attr price for the latest date would be then 3,2.

What I have so far

```
    select sum(iv.price * (count(distinct(u.attr)))) 
from userprofiles u , informationvalues iv
    where iv.attr = u.attr and u.userid ='ann'
 and  iv.dateofvalue = (select max(dateofvalue) from informationvalues)
```

I don't know what I am missing to get the value 3.2 for the userid 'ann'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to *correlate* the subquery to the outer query, so it gives you the latest date *per attribute* rather than the overal latest date.

Also it is unclear to me why you need that computation with `count(distinct ...)` in the outer query.

Side note: *always* use modern, standard join syntax (with the `on` keyword) rather than implicit joins (with a comma in the `from` clause).

I would suggest:

```
select sum(iv.price) total_price 
from userprofiles u 
inner join informationvalues iv on iv.attr = u.attr   -- standard join syntax
where 
    u.userid ='ann'
    and iv.dateofvalue = (
        select max(iv1.dateofvalue) 
        from informationvalues iv1 
        where iv1.attr = iv.attr                       -- correlation
    )
```

Comment: thank you for your solution, could you elaborate why you used a "inner" join instead of a join ?

Comment: @Lyaso: welcome. `inner join` is a synonym for `join`, that's just a coding style.

Comment: What I don't get is, how the "where iv1.attr = iv.attr " inside the subquery works. Why can't I define this outside ?

Comment: @Lyaso: the outer query cannot "see" inside the subquery. Meanwhile, the subquery can access the values from the outer query. So the correlation happens in the subquery, and returns the proper value to the outer query.